# Windows to Windows Connectivity

Tags: windows

I want to automate a job in my windows server,Can any one please share some idea or initiation for this scenario?

I like to connect from my windows server to another windows server and download the oracle database table in .csv format and place in my system folder.And this job should run every day.

Basically, i'm into UNIX platform but i want to do this in WINDOWS platform,    Thank you for your support!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a small application to do that, you can use ASP.NET to build the application, or PHP, but the latter will require more effort to setup the environment. After the application built, you will have to create windows task scheduler to execute the application at a specified time.

Comment: Can we improve this scenario by directly connecting to oracle database from our windows server and download the required table to our system?

Comment: It can't be done that way.
The analogy is windows server is just like our house, and the one who can take items from the other house is you, the application :)